# Understanding Zorn's lemma x

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[Zorn's lemma is used](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZornsLemma.html) on partially ordered sets. So, Why not total order or well-ordered sets? Can you explain?

Comment: Totally ordered and well ordered sets are partially ordered.

Answer (score 5):

All total orderings are partial orderings, and all well orderings are total orderings. So, Zorn's lemma applies to them. However, Zorn's lemma is not *useful* for relations known to be total orderings, because then the entire set is a chain. Because of this, the hypothesis of Zorn's lemma (that every chain has an upper bound) immediately implies the conclusion (that there is a maximal element), without the need to appeal to Zorn's lemma itself.